# Bearer Api Authentication using PHP (curl)

Tags: php, curl, post, bearer-token

I'm trying to use brandfetch api with the bearer authentication. I tried this with my api from brandfetch and got the response ... The response is below . Is there anything I'm doing it wrongly?

```
$access_key = "zjH2XGHFCWSvsMR3o2JNTHuaueHDnDVWfcKTXH59SJw=";
$curl = curl_init();
                
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.brandfetch.io/v2",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"url\":\"https://www.google.com\"}\n",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer $access_key",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}


Response is this  : {"message":"Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header. Authorization=Bearer zjH2XGHFCWSvsMR3o2JNTHuaueHDnDVWfcKTXH59SJw="}

``
```

Comment: according to the [docs](https://docs.brandfetch.com/#e2e11a14-c3d6-413e-8dc1-5b6c05dea1a3) there is only one endpoint and its [GET] `https://api.brandfetch.io/v2/brands/:domainOrId` try that instead, check the docs you also seem to passing URL wrong.

Comment: Ait, i did check the documentation but i thought it wasnt needed.. I will try that too and see